# Google Place api key stopped working

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I am using **GooglePlace Api** to get Goole places. All of sudden my api key stoped working. I have made the another key that key is also not working.
All api's are also enable. Can any one guide me, what could be the reason?
[image]

Comment: did you enable your key on Google console.

Comment: Yes. It was enable from Console.

Comment: Did you check your usage in the developer console? Places API has 1000 daily requests quota by default. You are likely exceeding the quota.